# Self-contained formalization of random variables?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, set-theory, measure-theory, foundations

I have not been able to find any formalization of random variables that supports construction of new random variables dependent on previously constructed ones. In what I have found, a random variable $A$  is a measurable function from a fixed probability space $(Ω,F,P)$ to a measurable space $(X,E)$. But that means that we have to fix $Ω$ first before we can define $A$. If later we want to define another random variable $B$ that depends on $A$, we are stuck. I know that in many cases we can 'backtrack' and define $Ω$ to accommodate all the random variables that we want to have, but I want to know if it is possible to avoid that, and I would love to know of any references. I believe it may be possible to do it by defining a random variable to carry a set of probability spaces that it depends on, rather than just one probability space, but I am unable to find any reference for such a notion.

For example, what if I want a definable function $f$ on the ordinals such that $f(k)$ for each ordinal $k$ is a random variable that with probability $1/3$ is an independent uniformly random bit and otherwise is equal to the parity of the minimum ordinal $m$ such that there is an increasing function $g : k_{≥m}{→}k$ satisfying $∀i{∈}k_{≥m}\ ( \ g(i)<i ∧ f(g(i)) = f(i) \ )$? This seems conceptually well-defined, but we definitely cannot hope to have a sample space large enough to accommodate it.

To make clear what I am looking for, is there a definable class $RV$ (over ZFC) of random variables, such that we can state things like ( for every real-valued $A,B∈RV$ there is some $C∈RV$ such that $C = A$ with probability $1/3$ and $C = B$ with probability $1/3$ and $C = A+B$ with probability $1/3$ ). By "... with probability ..." I mean that we have a definable function $peq$ (over ZFC) that maps each pair of random variables to the probability that they are equal, and so we would literally have the theorem (where $RRV$ is the class of real random variables on which addition is definable):

$∀A,B{∈}RRV\ ∃C{∈}RRV\ ( \ peq(A,C) = peq(B,C) = peq(A+B,C) = 1/3 \ )$.

This we cannot do if we do not have a self-contained formalization of random variables. Of course, we must also have all other properties of random variables. So an answer would have to show how to set up both $RV$ and suitable definable functions that allow us to carry out probability theory axiomatically.

After I added the second example above, an answer was posted that works for real random variables each with finite dependencies. But the method used is simply to create a large enough sample space to accommodate all of those random variables, so it cannot handle my first example (an $Ord$-length sequence of dependent random variables).

Here is an anecdote from Fremlin ([Measure Theory Chapter 27](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/cont27.htm)): "*[A probabilist] did not believe in the space $Ω$ in the first place, and if it turns out to be inadequate for his intuition he enlarges it without a qualm. Loève calls probability spaces ‘fictions’, ‘inventions of the imagination’ in Larousse’s words; they are necessary in the models Kolmogorov has taught us to use, but we have a vast amount of freedom in choosing them, and in their essence they are nothing so definite as a set with points.*" In a similar sense, the motivation for my question is to formalize random variables so that no 'enlargement' of any sample space is necessary.

Comment: For your example, can't you represent $f$ through an Ord-length directed system of approximations, i.e. $\langle (f \restriction \alpha, \Omega_{\alpha}), \alpha \in \text{Ord} \rangle?$

Comment: I don't think that $f$ is any more conceptually well-defined than $\mathsf{Ord}$ itself, so I don't see a problem with it not being an object in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the picture here. Can you give a simple example of a situation where we need to "backtrack" w/r/t $\Omega$? I don't think I see what you mean.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? I cannot conceive of any situation in which one might want to construct such a function $f$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Formally, in the middle of a proof we might construct a random variable $A$, which according to the usual definition requires specifying a sample space $Ω$, which is a part of $A$. In a later part of a proof, if we further want to construct another random variable $B$ that depends on $A$, we cannot exactly do so. What we can do is to construct a *different* random variable $A'$ that has the same distribution as $A$, together with a $B$ with the desired dependency. This seems to fail if $A$ is itself dependent on other things; we would need to backtrack all the way.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: The goal is not that $f$, but that is the clearest example that seems to illustrate the problem that I wish to solve. Ultimately, the goal is to have self-contained random variables, not to have to change the sample space every time I want to construct new dependent random variables.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: Yes I did think about a directed system, but the point of my question was whether we did not have to go through such an indirect approach. Is it really necessary (as losif Pinelis claims in an answer below) to have a joint measurable space before we can construct dependent random variables? I do not think so...

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a "probability logic." [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-012-0046-8) might give you some pointers on how one could do that.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks, indeed another way to phrase my question would be to ask for a kind of axiomatization of a (proper) class of random variables. But I'm afraid I cannot see how that paper is related to my goal.

Comment: Should it be $i < g(i)$ (you say the function is increasing)? Also, when $k$ is a finite ordinal, I'm supposed to interpret this as $m=k$, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins: No. As per standard terminology, $g:k_{≥m}{→}k$ is increasing iff $∀i,j∈k_{≥m}\ ( \ i < j ⇒ g(i) ≤ g(j) \ )$. Strictly increasing iff "$≤$" is replaced by "$<$". Doesn't really matter here which of the two you want to. The condition says informally: "the subsequence of bits from position $m$ to less than $k$ shifts to an identical subsequence with strictly earlier indices at each position". For example if the sequence starts $(0,1,1,0,0,1,...)$ and $k = 6$ then $m = 3$ witnessed by the increasing function $\{(3,0),(4,0),(5,1)\}$.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I understand now.

Comment: @SamHopkins: And yes $m$ may be $k$ in the 'worst case' that there is no shift of the desired kind possible (since vacuously there is a function of the desired kind on the empty domain $k_{≥k}$).

Comment: In your vaguely conceived theory of random variables, how do you propose we avoid the following Russell-like paradox: for any class of random variables $V,$ we can define a fair coin flip independent from each variable $A \in V.$ My point is, it's not clear we can even develop a theory of arbitrary coin flips, let alone arbitrary random variables.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: We of course cannot deal with proper classes of random variables. I didn't ask for anything like that; note that the definable function I asked for has each random variable only depending on set-many 'previous' random variables. So what's the problem?

Comment: Then it should be possible to describe your universe of random variables via one giant Ord-length directed system, where at stage $\alpha$ we add in all random variables of set rank $\le \alpha$ of all possible dependencies on previously constructed random variables. I doubt this will satisfy your intuition any more than my first comment did, but I really don't think any successful approach to your question will differ significantly from what I've described.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: That sounds interesting, actually. I did not think of constructing the entire class of random variables by rank. If you can sketch it in an answer, and achieve the desired $Ord$-length sequence of random variables, it would be better than the current 'answers'. I had a slight worry that we may need to use global choice, so if you don't need it then it would definitely be interesting. And, yes, while it isn't satisfactory from a formalization viewpoint, it may be that some insight into a better formalization may yet come out of your construction.

Comment: Another possible way would be to steal a hack from the category theorists, assume that there is a strong inaccessible, and only look at ordinals with rank below the inaccessible. Here one can simply work with a humongous probability space consisting of independent coin-flips.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Mm a humongous probability space of independent coin flips is a humorous idea! But it would be really odd if cutting off at an inaccessible is the easiest way even for random variables on sample spaces below that rank.

Comment: @user21820 You can do that for any cardinality bound on the number of random variables you need. The inaccessible is only needed so you can simulate the class of ordinals as a set.

Comment: Don't you already hit problems at the first uncountable ordinal? You can have an uncountable collection of coin flips, but the space $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$ comes with the product $\sigma$-algebra. The condition you're describing on the other hand isn't measurable with respect to this.

Comment: @MartinHairer: You may be right, but it seems fine to my intuition... Suppose there is a problem, namely there is no random variable representing the first $k$ bits for some ordinal $k$. Then there is a minimum such $k$. If indeed Elliot's idea works, then for each $i<k$ we can pick a representation of the random variable for the first $i$ bits in the proposed directed system, and so can piece the random sequences together up to length $k$. Even if that doesn't work, are you sure that it is impossible, and can you explain why my intuition fails?

Comment: @user21820 Not sure I understand your comment. Your objection seems to be that it shouldn't be hard to glue together all the $f(i)$'s for $i < \omega_1$. That's indeed the case by Kolmogorov's extension theorem, but I don't see how this is related to my comment. The problem isn't with glueing together the $f(i)$'s for $i < \omega_1$ but with defining $f(\omega_1)$ once you've done that, since the product $\sigma$-algebra isn't large enough to contain the event you use in your definition.

Comment: @MartinHairer: Ah so that's where it goes wrong. I could repair my example such that each $f(k)$ has only countably many dependencies, but I will just settle for Michael's answer even though it doesn't exactly fulfill the goal I had in mind. And thanks for your comments!

Comment: You might be interested in Alex Simpson's approach to synthetic probability theory, where the goal is to formalize random variables directly without the usual machinery (even if finding models for the axioms might require some measure theory). See e.g. this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtsBsLM9ofk However, I'm not sure if the current formulation of the theory captures the particular example you had in mind, since IIRC it seems to be best-equipped to discuss things happening on standard Borel probability spaces (under the hood).

Comment: @MarttiKarvonen: Your comment is much appreciated! I don't have the time now to take a look, but from your brief description it already sounds very much like the kind of thing I am looking for, so I will definitely delve into it later! =)

Comment: @MarttiKarvonen: I've looked at Alex Simpson's talk. It's really very interesting, but slightly unfortunate that it is technically not compatible with AC, even though this choice makes it simpler in some aspects, such as in having every subset of the possible values being measurable, and in defining conditional expectation. It does go in a similar direction that I wanted, namely 'synthetic' axiomatization of probability theory, even if it doesn't exactly address the issue of dependencies. So thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition:** Let $\kappa$ be some infinite number cardinal number. There exists a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\nu)$ that carries $\kappa$ independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and such that
such for every family $\langle g_i\rangle_{i\in I}$ of real-valued random variables with $\#I\leq\kappa$ and every probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^I\times\mathbb{R}^J$ with $\#J\leq\omega$ and $\mathbb{R}^I$-marginal equal to the joint distribution of $\langle g_i\rangle_{i\in I}$, there exists a family of random variables $\langle g_i\rangle_{i\in J}$ such that the joint distribution of $\langle g_i\rangle_{i\in I\cup J}$ equals $\mu$. $$~$$

One can take
$\Omega={0,1}^{\kappa^+}$, $\Sigma$ the product-$\sigma$-algebra, and $\nu$ the fair coin-flipping measure. The proposition can be proven using ideas from [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00199-014-0815-1).

The proposition shows that one can find a probability space that can carry a lot of nontrivial random variables and such that one can always add ex-post a countable number of random variables at a time whose distribution relates in any way to the other random variables. One never runs out of space; there is no need to enlarge the underlying probability space.

This is probably more than enough for any reasonable probabilistic argument, but works with only set-many random variables. If one wants to do this with random variables indexed by the class of ordinals, one could do this by viewing the class of all sets as a genuine set in a larger universe that contains a strongly inaccessible cardinal; this seems to be the preferred method of foundation-conscious category theorists for dealing with similar size problems.

Comment: Thanks! I think this comes closest to addressing my question, even if it doesn't say whether the weird $Ord$-length random bit sequence is possible or not. (Martin Hairer thinks it is problematic.)

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand\Om\Omega\newcommand\ga\gamma$
I think all you need to do is clarify/formalize the terms you are using.

Given a measurable space $(X,E)$, let us say that random variables (r.v.'s) $A_1$ and $A_2$ with values in $(X,E)$ defined on probability spaces $(\Om_1,F_1,P_1)$ and $(\Om_2,F_2,P_2)$ are equivalent if they have the same distributions (that is, pushforward measures): $P_1A_1^{-1}=P_2A_2^{-1}$.

Then, for each measurable space $(X,E)$, there is a natural one-to-one correspondence between the set of all probability spaces $(X,E,\mu)$ over the given measurable space $(X,E)$ and the set of all equivalence classes of r.v.'s with values in $(X,E)$. This follows because, for any probability space $(X,E,\mu)$, the identity map of $X$ is a r.v. defined on the probability space $(X,E,\mu)$ with values in $(X,E)$, and the distribution of this identity map is $\mu$.

Now, when you say "we want to define another random variable $B$ that depends on $A$" (in a certain way), the only natural interpretation of this seems to be the following: you have/know the probabilities of the "joint events" of the form $\{A\in S,B\in T\}:=(A,B)^{-1}(S\times T)$ for some measurable spaces $(X,E)$ and $(Y,F)$, all $S\in E$, and all $T\in F$. In other words, you have/know the "joint" distribution (say $\ga$) of a random pair $(A,B)$ in some measurable space of the product form $(X\times Y,E\otimes F)$, and you want to have a probability space on which a random pair $(A,B)$ with distribution $\ga$ is to be defined.

Well, then you need to do almost nothing: as in the previous paragraph, just let $(A,B)$ be the identity map of $X\times Y$. Then $(A,B)$ will be a r.v. defined on the probability space $(X\times Y,E\otimes F,\ga)$ with values in $(X\times Y,E\otimes F)$, and the distribution of this identity map will be $\ga$. **Added:** In particular, each of the so-defined r.v.'s $A$ and $B$ will be defined on the probability space $(X\times Y,E\otimes F,\ga)$: $A$ is the map $X\times Y\ni(x,y)\mapsto x\in X$ and $B$ is the map $X\times Y\ni(x,y)\mapsto y\in Y$.

Similarly one can deal with any family of r.v.'s in place of a random pair $(A,B)$.

---

A short summary: once you have the joint distribution of all your random variables, you automatically and effortlessly have a probability space on which all your random variables can be defined. And if you do not have the joint distribution, then you cannot construct appropriate random variables.

---

**Response to the comment by the OP:**

You wrote: "*What your last paragraph is saying is that, given any desired joint distribution of a conceptual set of random variables (it isn't a set since we haven't constructed them yet), there **exists** random variables with that joint distribution. I agree, but this is precisely what I want to avoid.*"

I think your language is very imprecise. First here, it does not make sense to talk about the "joint distribution of a [...] set of random variables". In particular, the phrase "the joint distribution of the set $\{A,B\}$ of r.v.'s" has no meaning. Instead, we may want to talk about the joint distribution of the random pair $(A,B)$ (which is in general different from that of $(B,A)$) or of the random pair $(A,A)$ (rather than of the set $\{A,A\}=\{A\}$). More generally, we can talk about the joint distribution of any **family** (not set!) of r.v.'s.

Next, the existence of a family of r.v.'s with a given joint distribution is a (very simple) fact, and you cannot possibly avoid facts, even if "this is precisely what [you] want to avoid."

You also wrote: "*Can you address my suggested idea that a random variable carries a set of probability spaces instead of just one? Then we do not need to modify the probability space in random variable $A$ when constructing another random variable $B$ that depends on $A$.*"

I think your idea for a r.v. to "carry" a set of probability spaces instead of just one was addressed in the beginning of my answer, by suggesting to consider the equivalence classes of r.v.'s (defined on possibly different probability spaces) with the same distribution. So, as now noted in the **Added** sentence above, if you have a r.v. $B$ in addition to $A$, you don't need to modify anything; you can just automatically and immediately choose a certain probability space (namely, $(X\times Y,E\otimes F,\ga)$), which is one of the probability space "carried by $A$".

Comment: What your last paragraph is saying is that, given any desired joint distribution of a conceptual set of random variables (it isn't a set since we haven't constructed them yet), there **exists** random variables with that joint distribution. I agree, but this is precisely what I want to avoid. Can you address my suggested idea that a random variable carries a set of probability spaces instead of just one? Then we do not need to modify the probability space in random variable $A$ when constructing another random variable $B$ that depends on $A$.

Comment: @user21820 : I have added a response to your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think you get my point at all. Firstly, ZFC does not permit you to construct the equivalence class of all random variables that are equivalent to $A$. Secondly, what you are doing is precisely the 'backtracking' that I do not want to have. I do not believe that it is necessary to do it the way you say.

Comment: @user21820 : Again, I believe that the whole problem is that you use very imprecise language and, sometimes, you use plainly meaningless phrases such as "the joint distribution of a set [rather than of a family] of r.v.'s". To begin clearing this up, you may want to try to explain the meaning of your clause "we want to define another random variable $B$ that depends on $A$". In particular, will it do, if I define $B$ as $A$? Then $B$ will depend on $A$ if e.g. $A$ is a real-valued r.v. such that $P(A=a)\ne1$ for all real $a$.

Comment: I have added a bit to my question. I do not think the problem is with imprecise language. Obviously I didn't mean a ZFC-set of random variables (after all I said "conceptual set"). And I am not sure why it is unclear what "dependent random variables mean" as it is clear enough from the first example I gave concerning a definable function from $ORD$ to random variables, which you did not address in your answer at all.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
The latest clarification by the OP appears useful, giving rise to the following construction.

---

Define the class $RV$ as follows.

Let $\Om:=\{0,1\}^\N$, let $F$ be the Borel $\si$-algebra with respect to the product topology over $\Om$, and let $P$ be the product probability measure $\la^{\otimes\N}$, where $\la$ is the uniform distribution on $\{0,1\}$. Clearly, the probability space $(\Om,F,P)$ is isomorphic to the Lebesgue probability space over the interval $[0,1]$.

Say that a subset $S$ of $\N$ is thin if the cardinality of $S\cap[n]$ is $o(n)$ as $n\to\infty$, where $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Let now $RV$ be the set of all (say real-valued) random variables (r.v.'s) $A$ defined on the probability space $(\Om,F,P)$ such that for some thin $S=S_A\subset\N$, some Borel function $f=f_A\colon\{0,1\}^S\to\R$, and all $\om\in\Om$ we have
$$A(\om)=f(\om|_S);$$
that is, $A\in RV$ iff $A(\om)$ depends only on the values of the function $\om$ on a thin subset $S$ of $\N$.

Clearly, for any $k\in\N$, any r.v.'s $A_1,\dots,A_k$ in $RV$, and any Borel function $g\colon\R^k\to\R$, we have $g(A_1,\dots,A_k)\in RV$. This follows because the union of finitely many thin subsets of $\N$ is thin.

Moreover, for any $k\in\N$ and any probability distribution $\nu$ on $\R^k$, there are r.v.'s $A_1,\dots,A_k$ in $RV$ such that the "joint" distribution of $(A_1,\dots,A_k)$ is $\nu$. This follows because there are infinite thin subsets of $\N$.

Further, for any countable set $T$ and [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) family of finite-dimensional probability distributions on $\R^S$ indexed by finite subsets $S$ of $T$, there is a family $(A_t)_{t\in T}$ of r.v.'s in $RV$ with the given finite-dimensional distributions. This follows because there is a countable set of disjoint infinite thin subsets of $\N$.

Furthermore, for any r.v.'s $A$ and $B$ in $RV$ there is a r.v. $K\in RV$ such that $K$ is independent of $(A,B)$ and $P(K=1)=P(K=2)=P(K=3)=1/3$. Letting then
$$C:=A\,1(K=1)+B\,1(K=2)+(A+B)\,1(K=3),$$
we get a r.v. $C\in RV$ such that "$C$ is $A$ with probability $1/3$, $C$ is $B$ with probability $1/3$, and $C$ is $A+B$ with probability $1/3$", as desired.

---

In view of the [Borel isomorphism theorem](http://math.iisc.ac.in/%7Emanju/MartBM/RaoSrivastava_borelisomorphism.pdf), here instead of real-valued r.v.'s we may consider r.v.'s with values in arbitrary Polish spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, which I suppose works for finitely many real random variables (or random variables with values in some Polish space). Unfortunately, this is once again backtracking, since you're essentially creating a large enough sample space just to accommodate all random variables to be constructed, via the use of thin subsets so that there is always enough 'leftover random bits'. In fact, I don't think this even works if we want to prove theorems involving infinite sequences of dependent real random variables.

Comment: Furthermore, how does this address my question about a definable function on $ORD$? Please don't avoid that question, because it is a very **precise** test. I don't want a formalization that cannot construct that, unless it is impossible.

Comment: @user21820 : I don't see any backtracking (going back to what?) in this construction, unless the term "backtracking" is conceived as totally comprehensive, to embrace everything imaginable, including staying in place and going forward. On the other hand, I cannot imagine any working probabilist who would be interested in having all r.v.'s enumerated, in a definable or any other way. Indeed, in theoretical work in probability we do not see any problem at all if the probability space needs to be enlarged; and why would we?

Comment: Previous comment continued: On the other hand, in specific probabilistic models (such as various random graphs, for example), the probability space arises quite naturally. If one then wants to further detail the model, then the probability space will **naturally** be enlarged, which is the desirable flexibility.

Comment: The term "definable function (over ZFC)" is a precise technical notion, and so is the class of ordinals. If you cannot address that question about a definable function from $Ord$ to random variables, you simply have not answered my question.

Comment: @user21820 : What I said about enumeration of r.v.'s was a comment about your question, not about the answer. Of course you are free to ask any kinds of questions. However, I think other people are equally free to comment on your questions.

Comment: Yes, you're free to say whatever you like. Unfortunately, you have not answered my question. Thanks for your attempts, anyway.

Comment: @user21820: it seems Iosif gave a very reasonable answer to the question you wrote in the paragraph starting "To make clear..." and ending "...axiomatically."

Comment: @SamHopkins: No Iosif didn't, and I already adequately explained why. Iosif only managed to deal with **real** random variables where you can construct new random variables each of which depends on **finitely many** previous ones, whereas I asked for formalization of **all** random variables.....

Comment: @user21820 : It is incorrect to say that the construction in this answer deals only with finitely many random variables. Indeed, the set of $RV$ of r.v.'s contains at least as many r.v.'s as there are probability distributions (on $R$ and on any Polish space); thus, uncountably many r.v.'s. Moreover, the paragraph I have just added shows that within this construction one can deal with countably many r.v.'s in $RV$ **at once**.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Look, from the beginning I already said that you failed to deal with arbitrary random variables. I made a clear distinction between the desired class $RV$ of all random variables and the class $RRV$ of real random variables. Your just added paragraph shows that you can construct (at once) a countable family of real random variables with consistent desired distributions, but fails to show closure under **arbitrary** functions on countable sequences of real random variables. Read my comments again carefully.

Comment: @user21820 : arbitrary functions do not preserve the measurability.

Comment: I know that... But *whenever* it preserves measurability, the class should be closed under it. Your whole approach is to set up a large enough sample space to squeeze all your real random variables 'into' it, which is completely ignoring my question. Unless you *actually answer* my question for the $Ord$-length sequence, which you have deliberately ignored repeatedly, this shall be my last response to you.

Comment: @user21820 : I agree that I have not provided an enumeration of all r.v.'s in the world. But may I ask you: Why would you or anyone else be interested in having such an enumeration? What use would it be of?

Comment: You keep talking about "enumeration of r.v.s" when I **did not**. As I said before, what I asked for is a **definable function** from $Ord$ to random variables that satisfies some property, **not at all** an enumeration of all random variables... If you don't understand ordinals, please don't make false assumptions about what I asked. Until you understand my question, you of course won't see any use.

Comment: @user21820 : OK, let me restate the question: Why would you or anyone else be interested in having "a **definable function** from $Ord$ to [the class of all? -- I.P.] random variables" that would provide "formalization of **all** random variables"? What use would it be of?

Comment: You're mangling my question again... I asked for such a definable function because you cannot do it without a sufficiently powerful formalization of all random variables. Look at your own answer; it obviously cannot handle any random variable on a sample space with cardinality greater than the one you chose. Elliot Glazer clearly understood that issue (hence he suggested a directed system of an $Ord$-length sequence of *sample spaces*), because **one single sample space will definitely fail**.

Comment: @user21820 : I used your own phrases in their entirety when stating the question, adding only "Why would you or anyone else be interested in having" and "that would provide", for context/grammar, and also trying to fix the meaningless phrase " function from $Ord$ to random variables".

Comment: @user21820 It seems to me that the _whenever it preserves measurability_ disclaimer is stronger than you may realise. In particular, it implies that one only ever adds new random variables depending on countably many of the previous ones. For the same reason, your example does not seem meaningful to me, for reasons completely unrelated to $Ord$ not being set-sized, see my comment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

- Although by definition a random variable is a measurable function defined on a probability space, abstract formulation of the concept of a random variable seems, to some extent, possible: one can think of (real- or complex-valued) random variables as elements of a commutative unital $C^*$ algebra, equipped with a linear functional called expectation that sends the unit to $1$. (And if one drops commutativity, one arrives in the world of non-commutative probability.)
- "Functions that take values in the class of random variables" are most commonly called stochastic processes. That is, the second paragraph of your question asks for a stochastic process indexed by a class rather than a set, with given properties. Or — equivalently, I think — a *single* random variable taking values in the class of $\operatorname{Ord}$-indexed functions (is this a class?). Unfortunately I know next to nothing about foundations of mathematics, and have no idea what the answer is.
- Given the first point of this comment, your question about $\operatorname{Ord}$-indexed stochastic process can be rephrased in the language of $C^*$ algebras — is there a $C^*$-algebra-like object (if I understand correctly, a "definable class") that can accommodate such a process. This makes your question very loosely related to probability, as a similar question can be asked about essentially any other mathematical structure. (I believe this was the source of misunderstanding in your discussion with Iosif Pinelis.)
- The question about the class of all random variables is, I believe, addressed in Michael Greinecker's excellent answer. This approach is, however, extremely exotic for a probabilist like me, and again not really related to probability. (I can give essentially the same questions in the context of, say, finite sets: is there a class of finite sets such that for any two of them there is another one such that it shares exactly one element with both of the two. Is this any simpler?)
- Fremlin's anecdote is perhaps nice, but — believe it or not — this mysterious underlying probability space that nobody cares about is an extremely useful concept in probability theory. No other way of thinking about random variables seems to be more productive. Just like the internal structure in, say, manifold theory is usually well hidden, but still essential.